# Remove all child nodes except last using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file as such:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <e />
    <f />
  </b>
  <c>
    <g>
      <j />
    </g>
    <g>
      <j />
    </g>
    <g>
      <j />
    </g>
  </c>
  <d>
    <h>
      <i />
    </h>
    <h>
      <i />
    </h>
    <h>
      <i />
    </h>
  </d>
</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is to apply an XSL transformation to **only** get the **last** nodes of c and d (including their child nodes) along with the rest of the file, resulting in:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <e />
    <f />
  </b>
  <c>
    <g>
      <j />
    </g>
  </c>
  <d>
    <h>
      <i />
    </h>
  </d>
</a>
```

I am not experienced with XSLT and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally best to start with an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) and add exceptions, and then sometimes exceptions to the exceptions.

In this transform, the first template is the identity transform, the second skips children of `<c>` and `<d>`, and the third overrides that exclusion to include the last child of each `<c>` and `<d>` tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c/*|d/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="c/*[last()]|d/*[last()]">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had to modify your input xml to remove some spaces.  The construct `<x/ >` is not really valid according to the  [specification (section 3.1 Start-tags, end-tags, and empty-element tags)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags).

As noted in comments, this can be made shorter, using only one template in addition to the identity.  I wasn't able to get `[not(last()]` to work, but this shorter template does:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c/*[position() &lt; last()]|d/*[position() &lt; last()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and there may be improvements possible in the condition.

Which is better is of course a matter of taste.  I find my original response slightly clearer.

Comment: Why not add a `[not(last())]` predicate to the second template and be done with it?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, and it's probably a bit more efficient.  I just didn't think of it.

Comment: I've been trying to get michael's suggestion to work also and ended up with the following alternate solution right before seeing your edit:                                                               <xsl:template match="c/*[position() != last()]|d/*[position() != last()]" />

Comment: @DonRoby your explanation helped me greatly in an issue I was facing.  I never knew about the "identity transformation" and often wondered why I saw similar code in XSL files and what it was for.

Answer (score -2):

the predicate:

```
select="*[not(last())]"
```

will not work !

the processor have CONFUSINGLY TWO kinds of node-filtering:

```
1, boolean-filter
2. positional-filter
```

because the filter-group will wrongly output position ZERO:

```
not(123) == 0

select=*[ 0 ]
```

then the positional-filter will get precedence, before the boolean-filter.

and because ZERO position does not exist then it will throw ERROR,

and this error will REJECT all the predicate !!!

lastly, the SOLUTION for this problem is:

```
select="*[ position() < last() ]"
```

you welcome :)

Comment: You are right, it should be `[not(position()=last())]` or `[position()!=last()]`. And this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Your "solution" will not work, if only because `<` is a reserved character (and also because the selection needs to be more selective than `*` - as shown in the accepted answer). I also find your style (the excessive exclamation marks, and your condescending closing remark) quite distasteful. The provided answer is correct. and you are making a great big deal out of an offhand comment I made almost 9 years ago. Try finding a more productive use of your time.